# Call vector whose name is define in another vector

Tags: r, for-loop, vector

I'm quite new to the R world.
I'm trying to automatically create from each column of a data frame a vector whose name is the name of the header of this column and recall it when needed.

for the example I'll use the "mtcars" data frame given by Rtutorial

```
 # use mtcars dataframe and reduce it for this example purpose
  a=mtcars
  a=mtcars[1:3,2:5]

 # Store Column Names in a vector
 col=colnames(a)

 # use a for loop from 1 to Number of columns to create vectors that:
 # 1. store column values and 
 # 2. named as column header

 for (i in 1:length(col)) {
     assign(col[i],as.character(a[,i]))  
 }

#(So Far So Good), 
# Let'z try to do a simple print of all vector created by the for loop
 for (i in 1:length(col)) {
     print(col[i])
 }
```

**here is my question:**

this second loop prints the value of the vector col[i]
so basically for each iteration I obtain

- iter1: "cyl"
- iter2: "disp"
- iter3: "hp"
- iter4: "drat"

but what I would like to obtain is not the [*i*] value of *col* vector.
what I would like to have is the values contained inside the vector called as *col[i]*
so after that second loop I would lie to obtain:

- iter1: "6" "6" "4"
- iter2: "160" "160" "108"
- iter3: "110" "110" "93"
- iter4: "3.9"  "3.9"  "3.85"

Comment: There is absolutely no valid reason for doing this. It makes whatever you plan to do afterwards more difficult.

Comment: I know it seems complicated but right know is the fastest way I thought about to solve my real problem. Probably there will be plenty of reason for not doing it, as well as there will be plenty of better solution to solve my real problem but right now at my knowledge this is what I came up with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `get` function.

```
for (i in 1:length(col)) {
  print(get(col[i]))
}
#[1] "6" "6" "4"
#[1] "160" "160" "108"
#[1] "110" "110" "93" 
#[1] "3.9"  "3.9"  "3.85"
```

Answer (score 2):

What you need is `get`.

```
for (i in 1:length(col)) {
    print(get(col[i]))
}
```

Without it, you are printing the values of th vector `col`, not what is stored in the variables whose names are those.